# How to fill html input with random tag id and name in vb.net?

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm trying to fill a html input box, but it won't fill, because i can't get the value of the tag name or id, because it changes every time the page is  reloaded, here is the html code:

```
<input id="1b9b8d81-aead-4930-90de-4c20121bc2d6.loginForm.username" maxlength="50" name="1b9b8d81-aead-4930-90de-4c20121bc2d6:username" value="" tabindex="1" class="mail inpRad" type="text" crmwa_forminfo="e-mail|">
```

And here is what I tried to do in vb.net:

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
        For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "mail inpRad" Then

            webpageelement.SetAttribute("value", "loloolloolloollol")

        End If

    Next
```

It didn't work.. I need some clue to get it working.

Comment: This would be hardly impossible if the input id changes every time.

Comment: It looks like your test on `value` should probably be a test on `class`.  Your input has a value of blank so that `SetAttribute` line will not be hit unless you type "mail inpRad" into it

Comment: While I'm still thinking about it, using the class attribute is a fine alternative to identifying the element, but if you're really wanting to use the id/name, you could always parse out the known part (such as "username") and use that in your logic

Comment: How can I parse the known part? since it'll look for everything inside the " ", is there a way to enter a wildcard before? i tried  `GetElementById("*.username")` but it didn't work.

Comment: I didn't mean with the `GetElementById` method.  I just meant your existing logic could use the Id on the HtmlElement like `If webpageelement.Id.Contains(".username")) Then ...` Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is VB.NET/ASP.NET concatenating that guid part of the Id at run time?